# Why was running OpenSSL dhparam too fast?

Tags: openssl, diffie-hellman

I just generated Diffie-Hellman parameters and it seemed way too fast. The whole thing was over in under a second:

```
$ openssl dhparam -out /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem 2048
This is going to take a long time
..............................................+.++*++*
$
```

I'm running on a relatively new ECS t2.medium instance (2 VCPU, 4GB RAM).

So I ran it again and this time it printed 5918 characters and took about 30 seconds.

What happened the first time?

Comment: I'd say you just got lucky the first time. It's the thing about randomness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating Diffie Hellman parameters it takes the most time to create the modulo `p`, which is a big prime number. To create this, a semi-random number is taken and checked for primality. If you are lucky and you pick a prime number soon, the algorithm finishes quickly.

Specifically:

- [`BN_generate_prime_ex`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/bn/bn_prime.c#L201) calls [`probable_prime_dh_safe`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/bn/bn_prime.c#L623) that takes a random number and checks whether it is divisable by the first 2048 primes. If it is, it takes another random number, etc. If it finds a likely prime, it prints a dot.
- It calls [`BN_is_prime_fasttest_ex`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/bn/bn_prime.c#L300), which does the [Miller–Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test). It prints a '+' if the tested value is prime.
- It tests both `p` and `(p-1)/2` this way, and prints a `*` if both are prime. It tests it a couple of times to be really sure. For 2048 bits, it checks it [twice](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/9021a5dfb37fd3a6f7726f07ef0f27dcb71048e2/include/openssl/bn.h#L220). That is why you see `++*++*` on the end of the output.

It repeats these steps until it finds a number that is very likely to be prime. How many loops are necessary depends on chance.

[Openssl docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BN_generate_prime.html)

Comment: Is there any chance that there could be a flaw in EC2 or Xen that causes a well known prime to be found quickly?

Comment: Also, such a big cloud operator as Amazon could have patched the openssl library to outsource the dhparam generation to a mutualized resource (totally random guess here)